# kali linux - WiFi connected but can't surf the net

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, troubleshooting

> Preface #1 : I'm not using a Virtual Machine
>
> Preface #2 : during the installazion I skipped the Network Mirror step
>
> Preface #3 : I never used Linux before

I have a laptop and I can connect to my WiFi network.

The problem is that I can't connect to the outside world!

```
ping www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

Iceweasel won't work either.

This is my **ifconfig**
[image]

The Proxy is set to **None**

[image]

This is my Access Point configuration (IPv4)

[image]

And, since I skipped the Network Mirror configuration at installation time, I read on some forums I needed to add two lines in the **sources.list**

[image]

Please, I've been struggling for hours by now.

Does anyone of you know the reason of this issue?

**P.S:** Sometimes, I could load the Google page and I could make the ping work... umh, maybe my laptop network driver is just **too weak?** I'm far 3 meters from the router...

P.S2: I tried to connect my laptop to my router via Ethernet cable. It works! But why can't I connect via WiFi?

Comment: First of all get an IP address. As far as I see you don't have an IP address assigned in the wlan0 interface (ifconfig wlan0)...Your router should assign you one if it works as DHCP server, which most of them do... After that check that /etc/resolv.conf contains a DNS address (e.g. 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4) => nameserver 8.8.8.8

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do I assign an IP address to my wlan0?

Comment: sudo dhclient -r wlan0

Comment: ifdown wlan0 && ifup wlan0

Comment: Thanks for the availability
First of all I tried assigning my wlan0 an IP address, but it didn't seem to work. Screenshot > http://prntscr.com/bymr39
Then I checked the resolv.conf file and it turned out it's empty. Screenshot > http://prntscr.com/bymrpx
What's happening?

Comment: @burian.vlastimil here it is > http://prntscr.com/bymuho

Comment: @burian.vlastimil Ok here it is > http://prntscr.com/byn1da

Comment: But as @mmmint said, I still don't have an IP for wlan0

Comment: @burian.vlastimil ho hey! it's working!!! What made that work? What happened? haha, thanks guys!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Kali Linux you have just needed to run this first

```
airmon-ng check kill
```

> This command stops network managers then kill interfering processes left

Source and other useful information: https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airmon-ng